# Fetching Records from Collection having approximate 50000 records

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use pipeline aggregation to fetch records iteratively, 300(or as required by consumer) each from an array of 50000 records. In this case, customer having 50000 transactions. I cannot use skip/limit as consumer wants to fetch on another key on the collection on which we do not have index .

This is how it need to work - 
1. First Call to my REST API using key id as 220 and "requiredRecords"(parameter in Get call) as 300. So I should be able to get 300 records starting from key id 220
2. next call with Key Id as 520 and "requiredRecords" as 50 and so on up to 50000.

Appreciate any help as query is performing very slow currently and sometimes getting timed out as I do not have any filters.

Comment: How many matching documents do you reasonably expect (using the other field which does have the index) ?

Comment: Querying on 50k shouldn't be an issue !! How does your query look like & did you try to use `explain` & analyze why your query is failing ?

Comment: Have you created the index on the Key Id? If the index is created on Key id I think performance should be fine as Key Id will be sorted and database should fetch the records in no time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Documents are put in buckets with size of 250 each and I realised that key id does not have index and can be skipped as well. Example - Key Id 204 may be next number after key id 202. Therefore 203 is skipped or deleted.

Comment: @whoami - Currently I am firing query based on customer id(indexed) no so specific filter of criteria

Comment: @Devesh - I checked my Db again and we do not have index on key id as that could be duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by creating index on Key Id. Index does not need to be unique in the system. It is the primary key index which need to be unique. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

> db.CollectionName.createIndex({KeyId : 1})

Once the index is created you can check from the https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/ that your query will start using the index and it will be faster.